# Magento 2 : How to get collection of all sources "MSI (multi source inventory)?

Tags: magento2, module, multi-source-inventory

I have created a custom module and on my custom page, I want the collection of all the sources available on my website. Let's assume I have created 3 sources from backend like "US", "UK", "INDIA". 
Now, I want the collection of all resources available on my website

How could I achieve this functionality?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try following way:

```
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilderFactory;
use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceRepositoryInterface;

/**
 * @var SourceRepositoryInterface
 */
private $sourceRepository;

/**
 * @var SearchCriteriaBuilderFactory
 */
private $searchCriteriaBuilderFactory;

/**
 * Place constructor.
 *
 * @param SourceRepositoryInterface $sourceRepository
 * @param SearchCriteriaBuilderFactory $searchCriteriaBuilderFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    SourceRepositoryInterface $sourceRepository,
    SearchCriteriaBuilderFactory $searchCriteriaBuilderFactory
) {
    $this->sourceRepository = $sourceRepository;
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilderFactory = $searchCriteriaBuilderFactory;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
public function getAllOptions()
{
    if (!$this->_options) {
        /** @var SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder */
        $searchCriteriaBuilder = $this->searchCriteriaBuilderFactory->create();
        $searchCriteria = $searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
        $sources = $this->sourceRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
        foreach ($sources as $source) {
            $this->_options[] = [
                'value' => $source->getCountryId(),
                'label' => $source->getCountryId()
            ];
        }
    }
    return $this->_options;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sohel Rana